# Gaming write-to-disk amount

Tags: hard-drive, memory, graphics-card, performance

I'm wondering (and I can't seem to find any relevant information) how much does gaming specifically use in `disk writing`?

I know "gaming" is quite generic, but I'm comparing this to classic desktop usage, like internet browsing and using office software.

I've always thought that browsing / office would need MORE write-to-disk resources than gaming, because, well, you're literally saving files on your computer (temp files or "real" files).

When it comes to gaming, I assume that a LOT of it is loaded into the ram (main ram or graphic ram), and all of it is handled by the CPU/GPU. But what is really written on disk ? Please note, I only want to average/guess/measure the **writing**, the reading is obviously much much higher than any of the following numbers, and is of course way bigger than browsing/office use.

- Saved games (probably a <1mb text file per save)
- Replays (most likely the biggest of all, say something like 100Mo and I feel like i'm exagerating) ; note that replays don't always exist.
- Settings and persistent stuff (probably also a very small text file)

So all in all I wanna say you'd have <200Mo of writing throughout a game, but then, am I wrong?

If you need examples because you feel it is relevant, lets just aim for the big classic ones, Battlefield, Starcraft, stuff like that. But does it even matter in terms of writing?

That being said, my questions would be :

- What is written on the disk while playing games?
- What amount of data would that represent? Are we talking kb, mb? gb?

TL;DR :

- **How much data would be written on disk after 1 hour of playing starcraft 2**
- **How much data would be written on disk after 30 minutes of facebook & 30 minutes of writing an essay on Microsoft Word 2010**

Comment: There is no difference.  All programs are loaded into memory.  All programs have files accessed on the hdd.  What is written to the disk depends on the program.

Comment: I edited the end to be clearer about what i'm asking. Though your answer surprises me already

Comment: Your question is still extremely broad.  What is written to the disk depends on the software.  What amount of data would that would represent would depend on the program.  There is no standard answer to this question.

Comment: What about now? :D

Comment: You can install Sysmon from here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dn798348 and show what exactly is written while playing game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you information, I tested using Starcraft 2 during half an hour.
Tottal writes was about 300Mb.
so, to anser your question, it's not around many GB per game, but more about a few MB per game.

[Real Example](http://snag.gy/NTTA8.jpg)

Comment: Thanks brother, this seems pretty clear and reliable.
I hope you won.

Comment: you would see more `reads` from games since it loads files to memory often to improve performance. Which is why SSDs are so popular with gaming. they have awesome read speeds